# ¿Cómo se eliminan las células de un marco de datos si su contenido es de un cierto tipo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo una dataframe con preguntas y respuestas y me gustaria que para cada línea, para cada respuesta `Answeri`, si es una lista entonces nos deshacemos de ella. Aqui esta una parte de la dataframe:

```
Questions   Answers     Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5     Answer6     Answer7
19  What is you preference of room/suites with bal...   ['Preferred', 'Not preferred']  Preferred   Not preferred   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
20  How do you want your guestroom to look like?    ['Contemporary style guestrooms', ['18l...  Contemporary style guestrooms   ['18lKwM8N2EuQujkFj81pcSrt5bjy9wppKC8mjYQZp0L0...   Traditional style guestrooms    ['1OL5AUAqisiQBDrkNM0OQ0_NcHxmisM0y8I6OJpRcSdI...   Classical style guestrooms  ['17VZAwPRJucKzD21BluUD3aMUQnGzCOtfUPyn7vGLqhD...   NaN     NaN
```

Y me gustaria:

```
Questions   Answers     Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5     Answer6     Answer7
19  What is you preference of room/suites with bal...   ['Preferred', 'Not preferred']  Preferred   Not preferred   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
20  How do you want your guestroom to look like?    ['Contemporary style guestrooms', ['18l... ]     Contemporary style guestrooms      Traditional style guestrooms        Classical style guestrooms      NaN     NaN
```

Por lo momento solo tengo el agoritmo:

```
for row in enumerate(data.itertuples()):
    i = 0 
    answer = data['Answer'+ str(i)]
    while answer != np.NaN:
        if type(answer) == list:
            answer = np.NaN # Reemplaza la celda. Pero también tendrías que mover todos los del lado derecho de la celda.
```

Y obtengo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-234-e03a9780f5fb> in <module>
      5     i = 0
      6     question = data['Answer'+ str(i)]
----> 7     while question != np.NaN:
      8         if type(question) == list:
      9             question = np.NaN

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
   1478         raise ValueError(
-> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1481         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Saludos, Hace falta pongas el código de lo realizado;así mismo indiques el error (mensaje de ser posible) que te muestra o si es un resultado equivocado el que muestra indicar (con datos conocido) cual es el resultado que obtienes y cual debe ser.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr ¡Gracias por tu comentario! He actualizado con mi intento, el error y el resultado esperado

Comment: Puedes especificar que resultado esperas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirando los datos veo que las listas son simplemente strings. Para distinguir un string corriente de una lista mostrada como string, miramos el primer y último caracter, que tienen que ser "[" y "]"

Esta función evalúa si un valor es una lista o no. La comprobación se limita a revisar que empiece y termine con "[" y "]". Si es necesario, se puede hacer más estricta, chequeando que contenga valores separados por coma.

```
import pandas as pd 

def is_a_lista(valor):
    """ Evalua si el valor es una lista representada como string
    
    @param valor: El valor a probar.
    @return: True si es una lista.
    """
    return type(valor) is str and valor[0] == "[" and valor[-1] == "]"
```

Esta función recorre una fila. Cuando encuentra una celda con listas, corre todo el contenido de la fila una celda a la izquierda y agrega una celda en blanco al final (se puede ajustar)

```
def ajusta_fila(row):
    """ Ajusta una fila del dataframe, eliminando las celdas con listas

    @param row: Una fila
    @return: La fila, compactada y sin listas.
    @return: Un arreglo de indices (de row) donde se encontraron listas
    """
    salida = []
    indices = []

    for index in range(len(row)):
        valor = row[index]
        if is_a_lista(valor):
            indices.append(index)
        else:
            salida.append(valor)

    salida.extend([''] * (len(row) - len(salida)))
 
    return salida, indices
```

La fila original no se toca; la función retorna la nueva fila y un arreglo con los indices (de la fila original) en donde se encontraron listas. Esto lo uso luego para chequear los resultados.

Con esto estamos listos.

**Comprobación**

Ahora haremos un programa de comprobación.

Revisaremos cada fila de la siguiente manera: si se detectan listas, se imprime el valor de la celda original. Debajo mostramos las celdas anteriores/posteriores en la fila original. A continuación mostramos la parte correspondiente en la nueva fila, para revisar visualmente que el cambio esté bien hecho.

```
df = pd.read_csv("/home/candid/PycharmProjects/archivo.csv", dtype=str)

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if index > 10:
        break

    new_row, indices = ajusta_fila(row)
    desp = 0
    if len(indices):
        print()
        print("Fila %3d cambiada en columnas " % index)
        for indice in indices:
            print("   Celda %3d - Valor: %s" % (indice, row[indice]))
            print("   Contenido original")
            for i in range(indice-1, indice+3):
                print("         row[%d]=%s" % (i, row[i]))
            print("   --------------------")
            print("   Contenido modificado")
            for i in range(indice - desp - 1, indice - desp + 2):
                print("     new_row[%d]=%s" % (i, new_row[i]))
            desp += 1
        print()
        print()
```

Lo cual produce:

```
Fila   0 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed']
   Contenido original
         row[2]=When do you think your next vacation can start?
         row[3]=['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed']
         row[4]=nan
         row[5]=Multiple Choice
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=When do you think your next vacation can start?
     new_row[3]=nan
     new_row[4]=Multiple Choice
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['think', 'vacat', 'start']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['think', 'vacat', 'start']
         row[8]=In next 3 months
         row[9]=In next 6 months
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=In next 3 months
     new_row[7]=In next 6 months


Fila   1 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ["Doctor's availability in hotel", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care']
   Contenido original
         row[2]=What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?
         row[3]=["Doctor's availability in hotel", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care']
         row[4]=nan
         row[5]=Multiple Choice
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?
     new_row[3]=nan
     new_row[4]=Multiple Choice
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['prefer', 'medic', 'treatment', 'polici', 'addit', 'cost']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['prefer', 'medic', 'treatment', 'polici', 'addit', 'cost']
         row[8]=Doctor's availability in hotel
         row[9]=Ventilator availability in hotel
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=Doctor's availability in hotel
     new_row[7]=Ventilator availability in hotel


Fila   2 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only']
   Contenido original
         row[2]=What is your preferences of complementary breakfast?
         row[3]=['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only']
         row[4]=nan
         row[5]=Multiple Choice
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=What is your preferences of complementary breakfast?
     new_row[3]=nan
     new_row[4]=Multiple Choice
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['prefer', 'complementari', 'breakfast']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['prefer', 'complementari', 'breakfast']
         row[8]=Buffet breakfast with social distancing
         row[9]=Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=Buffet breakfast with social distancing
     new_row[7]=Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options


Fila   3 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
   Contenido original
         row[2]=What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery shops for the basic necessity items and packaged food?
         row[3]=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
         row[4]=nan
         row[5]=Likert Scale
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery shops for the basic necessity items and packaged food?
     new_row[3]=nan
     new_row[4]=Likert Scale
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['prefer', 'hotel', 'groceri', 'shop', 'basic', 'necess', 'item', 'packag', 'food']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['prefer', 'hotel', 'groceri', 'shop', 'basic', 'necess', 'item', 'packag', 'food']
         row[8]=Not preferred
         row[9]=2
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=Not preferred
     new_row[7]=2


Fila   4 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ['Collect keys at the counter maintaining social distancing', 'Collect keys at the KIOSK using booking bar-code', 'Online Keys using the mobile App']
   Contenido original
         row[2]=What is your preference of hotel check-in?
         row[3]=['Collect keys at the counter maintaining social distancing', 'Collect keys at the KIOSK using booking bar-code', 'Online Keys using the mobile App']
         row[4]=Consumer Personality
         row[5]=Multiple Choice
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=What is your preference of hotel check-in?
     new_row[3]=Consumer Personality
     new_row[4]=Multiple Choice
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['prefer', 'hotel', 'check']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['prefer', 'hotel', 'check']
         row[8]=Collect keys at the counter maintaining social distancing
         row[9]=Collect keys at the KIOSK using booking bar-code
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=Collect keys at the counter maintaining social distancing
     new_row[7]=Collect keys at the KIOSK using booking bar-code


Fila   5 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ['Pay at the counter maintaining social distancing', 'Pay at KIOSK', 'Online payment using the mobile App']
   Contenido original
         row[2]=What is your preference of payment during Check-out?
         row[3]=['Pay at the counter maintaining social distancing', 'Pay at KIOSK', 'Online payment using the mobile App']
         row[4]=Consumer Personality
         row[5]=Multiple Choice
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=What is your preference of payment during Check-out?
     new_row[3]=Consumer Personality
     new_row[4]=Multiple Choice
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['prefer', 'payment', 'check']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['prefer', 'payment', 'check']
         row[8]=Pay at the counter maintaining social distancing
         row[9]=Pay at KIOSK
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=Pay at the counter maintaining social distancing
     new_row[7]=Pay at KIOSK


Fila   6 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ['Travel date change is preferred at no cost', 'Cancellation at some minimal cost (based on hotel policy)', 'Cancellation with some amount refund and hotel coupons for next visit']
   Contenido original
         row[2]=What is your preference of hotel cancellation / travel date change policy?
         row[3]=['Travel date change is preferred at no cost', 'Cancellation at some minimal cost (based on hotel policy)', 'Cancellation with some amount refund and hotel coupons for next visit']
         row[4]=Consumer Personality
         row[5]=Multiple Choice
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=What is your preference of hotel cancellation / travel date change policy?
     new_row[3]=Consumer Personality
     new_row[4]=Multiple Choice
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['prefer', 'hotel', 'cancel', 'travel', 'date', 'chang', 'polici']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['prefer', 'hotel', 'cancel', 'travel', 'date', 'chang', 'polici']
         row[8]=Travel date change is preferred at no cost
         row[9]=Cancellation at some minimal cost (based on hotel policy)
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=Travel date change is preferred at no cost
     new_row[7]=Cancellation at some minimal cost (based on hotel policy)


Fila   7 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ['Guests are allowed in living room with precautions', 'Guest are allowed only in certain designated areas', 'No guests are allowed inside hotel']
   Contenido original
         row[2]=What is your preference of the guest policy?
         row[3]=['Guests are allowed in living room with precautions', 'Guest are allowed only in certain designated areas', 'No guests are allowed inside hotel']
         row[4]=Consumer Personality
         row[5]=Multiple Choice
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=What is your preference of the guest policy?
     new_row[3]=Consumer Personality
     new_row[4]=Multiple Choice
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['prefer', 'guest', 'polici']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['prefer', 'guest', 'polici']
         row[8]=Guests are allowed in living room with precautions
         row[9]=Guest are allowed only in certain designated areas
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=Guests are allowed in living room with precautions
     new_row[7]=Guest are allowed only in certain designated areas


Fila   8 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ['Regular concierge services', 'Online concierge service']
   Contenido original
         row[2]=What is your preference of the concierge service?
         row[3]=['Regular concierge services', 'Online concierge service']
         row[4]=Consumer Personality
         row[5]=Multiple Choice
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=What is your preference of the concierge service?
     new_row[3]=Consumer Personality
     new_row[4]=Multiple Choice
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['prefer', 'concierg', 'servic']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['prefer', 'concierg', 'servic']
         row[8]=Regular concierge services
         row[9]=Online concierge service
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=Regular concierge services
     new_row[7]=Online concierge service


Fila   9 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ['Hand sanitizer', 'Face mask', 'Face sheild', 'Hand gloves', 'Personal thermometers', 'Phone sanitizer', '', 1]
   Contenido original
         row[2]=What are the items you feel are essential in your room?
         row[3]=['Hand sanitizer', 'Face mask', 'Face sheild', 'Hand gloves', 'Personal thermometers', 'Phone sanitizer', '', 1]
         row[4]=Consumer Intentions
         row[5]=Multiple Choice
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=What are the items you feel are essential in your room?
     new_row[3]=Consumer Intentions
     new_row[4]=Multiple Choice
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['item', 'feel', 'essenti', 'room']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['item', 'feel', 'essenti', 'room']
         row[8]=Hand sanitizer
         row[9]=Face mask
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=Hand sanitizer
     new_row[7]=Face mask


Fila  10 cambiada en columnas 
   Celda   3 - Valor: ['Other people can be present maintaining social distancing', 'Individual usage based on time sharing (Not all time slots will be available)', 'I will not prefer Spa/Sauna at all']
   Contenido original
         row[2]=What is your preference of using the Spa/Sauna room?
         row[3]=['Other people can be present maintaining social distancing', 'Individual usage based on time sharing (Not all time slots will be available)', 'I will not prefer Spa/Sauna at all']
         row[4]=Consumer Intentions
         row[5]=Multiple Choice
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[2]=What is your preference of using the Spa/Sauna room?
     new_row[3]=Consumer Intentions
     new_row[4]=Multiple Choice
   Celda   7 - Valor: ['prefer', 'sauna', 'room']
   Contenido original
         row[6]=Hotel ABC
         row[7]=['prefer', 'sauna', 'room']
         row[8]=Other people can be present maintaining social distancing
         row[9]=Individual usage based on time sharing (Not all time slots will be available)
   --------------------
   Contenido modificado
     new_row[5]=Hotel ABC
     new_row[6]=Other people can be present maintaining social distancing
     new_row[7]=Individual usage based on time sharing (Not all time slots will be available)
```

Comment: Estaría buena que especificaras que estaba haciendo mal el OP, **es solo recomendación**.

Answer (score 3):

Para establecer como *NaN* (`np.nan`) aquellas celdas de un dataframe donde su valor es una lista puedes usar la función `apply`. Por ejemplo, teniendo este dataframe:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Questions": ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"],
        "Answers": [["A", "B"], "C", ["D", "E", "F"], "G"]
    }
)
```

`df` queda así:

```
  Questions    Answers
0        Q1     [A, B]
1        Q2          C
2        Q3  [D, E, F]
3        Q4          G
```

Creamos la siguiente serie de Pandas:

```py
s = df["Answers"].apply(lambda x: type(x) == list)
```

`s` queda así:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Answers, dtype: bool
```

`s` es una serie de Pandas de valores *booleanos*. La hemos obtenido como resultado de aplicar una función ***lambda*** (anónima) a cada uno de los elementos de la columna *Answers*, comparando su tipo con el tipo `list`.

Filtramos `df` a partir de `s` y en las filas resultantes, sustituimos el valor de *Answers* por un valor *NaN* (`np.nan`):

```py
df.loc[s, "Answers"] = np.nan
```

`df` queda así:

```
  Questions Answers
0        Q1     NaN
1        Q2       C
2        Q3     NaN
3        Q4       G
```

Comment: El OP no quiere eliminar filas completas, solo borrar aquellas respuestas que son listas. Cada celda en las columnas "Answeri" contiene una respuesta. Interpreto que tambièn quiere mover las respuestas a la izquierda cada vez que elimina una lista (no dejar celdas vacias).

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias. He editado mi respuesta respecto a lo de sustituir por "NaN" las celdas donde hay una lista. Respecto a lo otro, no lo entiendo. Voy a esperar a que el usuario explique mejor su pregunta y en ese caso volveré a editar mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

En realidad por lo visto tus datos son del mismo tipo `string`, así que filtrar por tipo no vas obtener lo que deseas. Debo entender que lo que quieres eliminar es este tipo de cadenas:

*'18lKwM8N2EuQujkFj81pcSrt5bjy9wppKC8mjYQZp0L0...'*
*'17VZAwPRJucKzD21BluUD3aMUQnGzCOtfUPyn7vGLqhD...'*

Allí una de las cosas que se puede hacer es filtrar por el tamaño de la cadena, así:

`df = df[df['AnswerX'].apply(lambda x: len(x)<30)]`

Así descartarás las cadenas con 30 o más caracteres, bueno allí tu verás que número es de tu conveniencia

Comment: Publica el código que fundamente tu respuesta. Sin un código es imposible verificar la certeza de tu respuesta. Los datos del OP estàn en [doc excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-HkjwgMxp5i_URalgz8w5YswniNMfPX2S6UZ0QUoka8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @CandidMoe el mismo OP puede verificar la certeza de la solución, ya que en la respuesta se da una posible solución.

Comment: Filtrar por el tamaño de los valores podría eliminar algunos valores que fueran largos pero válidos, ¿no?

Comment: En este caso no los hay, los posibles valores válidos tienen como maximo unos 30 caracteres

Answer (score 1):

Simple es mejor que complejo

```
df = pd.read_excel('merged.xlsx', index_col=0)

def fun(x):
    """Comprueba si el elemento es de tipo str y tiene menos de 50 caracteres
       si no lo es, lo elimina"""
    if type(x)==str:
        if len(x)<50:
            return x
    else:
        return ""

df.loc[21,'Answer0':] = df.loc[21,'Answer0':].apply(fun)
```

Comment: Eliminar valores según su tamaño podría eliminar algunos valores que fueran largos pero válidos, ¿no?

Comment: No en este caso, cuando las posibles respuestas estan acotadas a unas pocas y se sabe de antemano su longitud no hay problema.